# SELECT optimization using indecies

Tags: mysql, indexing, bigdata, where-clause

I am currently working with a dataset on word similarity. The data is very straightforward - you have pairs of words and a value of similarity. (Dog ; cat ; 43000)

I moved the raw data to a MySQL table, with the following **structure**:

```
word1_id: INT(11), Primary Key, Not Null

word2_id: INT(11), Primary Key, Not Null

value: INT(11), Not Null
```

When creating the table, I also defined an **index** (in addition to the Primary Key Index):

```
PRIMARY: BTREE, #1 word1_id, #2 word2_id

Word2: BTREE, #1 word2_id, #2 word1_id
```

There are 50.000 unique words. The data is completely static - once you import it into the table for the first time, nothing changes. **An example of the data is:**

```
word1_id ; word2_id ; value

1 ; 2 ; 48971754

1 ; 3 ; 75997417

1 ; 4 ; 18285783

..

1 ; 50000 ; 127

2 ; 3 ; 1046254

2 ; 4 ; 268081

...
```

**The goal is straightforward:** For a given target word (int), find the most similar words to it.

To do this, the table has to find all of the entries where a target INT (e.g. 436) is either in Column 1 (436 ; 543 ; 475652) or in Column 2 (72 ; 436 ; 934454) and return a sorted result, based on Column 3.

**My problem is the following:**

When looking for a target INT in the first column, the process is quick (e.g. 0.1 seconds).

```
SELECT
    value, word2_id
FROM
    cooccurrence
    WHERE
        word1_id = (436)
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

However, doing the same exact thing for a WHERE statement based on Column 2 takes a really long time (e.g. 1.5 - 10 seconds)

```
SELECT
    value, word1_id
FROM
    cooccurrence
    WHERE
        word2_id = (436)
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is it so much slower to do a WHERE based on Column 2, as opposed
   to Column 1. Shouldn't an indexed table have "sorted" versions of
   the data based on both columns?
2. Is this table structure a good way of tackling this issue? Are there
   any obvious optimisations to be made?
3. The ultimate goal is to have the distance (Column 3) as a FLOAT, and
   add a fourth column (INT) containing the Year. You would then view how the list of most similar words to a target changes over the years. This means the data (and table) would increase in size dramatically - e.g. from a few gigabytes to hundreds of gigabytes. Would this change
   things considerably in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY(word1_id, word2_id),
INDEX(word2_id, value, word1_id),
INDEX(word1_id, value, word2_id)
```

Let me dissect

```
SELECT
    value, word2_id
FROM
    cooccurrence
    WHERE
        word1_id = (436)
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

It goes something like this, using `INDEX(word2_id, value, word1_id)`:

1. Locate the last occurrence of `word1_id = (436)` in that index. (`WHERE`)
2. Scan backward. (`ORDER BY value DESC`)
3. At each item, deliver `value, word2_id`, (`SELECT`)

If you are only going to have about 50K words, change from `INT SIGNED` to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.  This will save 6 bytes per row of *this* table.

Once you have added another column and changed the query, what I have said will mostly be inadequate.  Let's see the `SELECT` that involves `year`.

When asking a performance query, provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  That way, we can point to it to say what clue(s) you are getting.